# OneTime ScheduleType -Windows Task Scheduler through Power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, taskscheduler

I am creating task scheduler through PowerShell deployment, I want to create One Time Task, I am using below script -

```
xScheduledTask SetupEmployeeProject
{
    TaskName = "Mobile Employee Pay"
    ActionExecutable = "$($Node.TargetRootFolder)\xxx\bin\Release\xxx.exe"
    ActionArguments = "employee"
    ScheduleType = "Once"
    RepeatInterval = 1
    StartTime ="7:00 PM"
    Ensure = "Present" 
    #ExecuteAsCredential = $serviceCreds
}
```

But when my deployment is done, I am seeing an error

> Failed to execute the powershell script.
>
> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: At least one of the values 'Once' is not supported or valid for property 'ScheduleType' on class 'xScheduledTask'. Please specify only supported values:

What should be the ScheduleType for one time job??

Comment: The [Wiki documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/xComputerManagement/wiki/xScheduledTask) suggests that `Once` is correct - "ScheduleType - Once, Daily, Weekly, AtStartup, AtLogOn". What versions of Windows and PowerShell are you using? Do you have a recent release of xSheduledTask?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version of `xScheduledTask` resource from the [`xComputerManagement` module](https://github.com/PowerShell/xComputerManagement)?

Comment: I was able to create other tasks but just this is failed..

Comment: I have Version: 1.0 Task Scheudler

Comment: Can you update the question with a link to the resource that you are using, and if possible to the documentation for it?

Comment: PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I don't understand what you are telling..

Comment: Where did you get `xScheduledTask` from? It has to be a DSC resource, or a class from a module, or something. Please provide a link to the site where you got that resource from.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician here is the DSC resource info   xScheduledTask                      4.0.0.0    xComputerManagement                 PSGallery

Comment: ###https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xComputerManagement/1.9.0.0
###https://github.com/PowerShell/xComputerManagement

Comment: It would be strange for this to be causing the issue, but according to the wiki your `RepeatInterval` should be a string  like `'00:01:00'` or something like that. Also, every example that has `RepeatInterval` also has `RepeatDuration` listed. For that matter, do you even want the task to repeat? Try just commenting out that line.